# Ordenar vetor numérico sem utilizar Bubble sort

Tags: java, array, classificação

Normalmente aprendemos na faculdade que, para ordenar vetores inteiros, usamos uma técnica chamada **[bubble sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)**:

```
int[] vetorOrdenado = new int[8];

    vetorOrdenado[0] = 2;
    vetorOrdenado[1] = 41;
    vetorOrdenado[2] = 12;
    vetorOrdenado[3] = 6;
    vetorOrdenado[4] = 5;
    vetorOrdenado[5] = 29;
    vetorOrdenado[6] = 17;
    vetorOrdenado[7] = 3;

    for(int i = 0; i < vetorOrdenado.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < vetorOrdenado.length - 1; j++){
            if(vetorOrdenado[i] < vetorOrdenado[j]){
                int aux = vetorOrdenado[i];
                vetorOrdenado[i] = vetorOrdenado[j];
                vetorOrdenado[j] = aux; 
            }

        }
    }
```

Essa técnica ordena um vetor de inteiros, como pode ser visto no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/OX5YLw).

Há outra maneira de se ordenar vetores numéricos sem utilizar laço dentro de laço, como no *bubble sort*? `Collections` não possui alguma forma de ordenar um vetor dessa forma?

Comment: Tem vários https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/ Na maior partte dos casos, o Quick sort bem otimizado funciona melhor. Bubble é bem ruim. O Java tem um algoritmo bem adequado pronto: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-byte:A-

Comment: @bigown esses métodos aí são só da versão 8? Percebi que não possui retorno, então ele ordena aproveitando o próprio vetor passado?

Comment: Eles são bem antigos. Ordenam *in-place*.

Comment: Dica de livro para aprender mais sobre algoritmos de ordenação: [Algoritmos. Teoria e Prática - Thomas Cormen](http://www.amazon.com.br/dp/8535236996)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O algoritmo de ordenação mais usado é disparado o [Quicksort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Ele não é bom para todos os casos, mas é bom em muitos e os mais comuns. A não ser que precise de performance extrema e sabe que o padrão típico dos dados se adéqua melhor para outros algoritmos é ele que deve ser escolhido.

O Java que não é bobo usa-o há muito tempo em uma otimização específica para aumentar o número de casos onde ele é adequado. Isto está disponível na própria [API do *array*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-byte:A-).

Para casos onde uma coleção precisa ser analisada contra ele mesma, tudo o que não se quer é uma complexidade O(N<sup>2</sup>), que é o comum neste caso. E o QS permite na maioria dos casos O(N logN), que é o melhor que se pode esperar no caso geral.

O [Radix](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) pode ser melhor ainda, mas é difícil implementá-lo.

[Comparação dos algoritmos](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).